# jQueryUI Enabling the link with respect of closing dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on jQuery UI dialog, [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mobj45kt/) for reference. If you observe on click of close window(dialog), the links are not getting enabled, however the links should be enabled based on relative window close. How can I relate the closing dialog window with the respective link and enable it again?

```
$(function() {

    function opener(params){
        var _params = params;
            for (var obj in _params){
                dialogOpener(_params[obj]);
            }
        function dialogOpener(selector){
            $('#'+selector.linkSelector).on('click', function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.stopPropagation();
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                if ($(ev.target).hasClass('disabled')) {
                        return false;
                } else{
                    $('#'+selector.moduleSelector).dialog({width: 800, position: 'top'}).load( url);
                    $(this).addClass('disabled');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    opener([
      { linkSelector: 'google', moduleSelector: 'googleModule'},
      { linkSelector: 'facebook', moduleSelector: 'facebookModule'},
      { linkSelector: 'yahoo', moduleSelector: 'yahooModule'},
      { linkSelector: 'gmail', moduleSelector: 'gmailModule'}
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an event that is fired on close of the dialog when you initialize your dialog box that re-enables the link. For instance your dialogOpener function could look something like this:

```
function dialogOpener(selector){
    $('#'+selector.linkSelector).on('click', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var selected = $(this);
        if ($(ev.target).hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
        } else{
            $('#'+selector.moduleSelector).dialog({
                width: 800, 
                position: 'top', 
                close: function(event,ui) { 
                    selected.removeClass('disabled'); 
                }
            }).load( url);
            selected.addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mobj45kt/2/

jQuery Dialog API for the close event: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close